# Передача ID через ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html

Всем привет.
есть кнопка "Лайк" при клике которой счетчик должен увеличиваться на 1. ID на сервер отправляется и в БД записывается новое значение счетчика, но на странице визуально ничего не происходит, лишь только после обновления страницы счетчик увеличивается. То есть по сути не работает ajax.

```
<p class="like-counter">
    <a data-id="<?=$id;?>" class="counter pull-right">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> <span><?=$comment['vote'];?></span>
    </a>
</p>

$('.like-counter').on('click', '.counter', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var id = $(this).data('id');
$.ajax({
    url: location.href,
    data: {id: id},
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (count) {
        count = parseInt(element.find('span').text());
        element.find('span').text(count+1);
        console.log(count);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Error, try again.');
    }
});
});
```

Я так понимаю в блоке success неверный код. Как сделать правильно?

Comment: get запрос для изменения?=))) И что если несколько раз нажать на кнопку like? На самом деле просто отдайте текущее количество лайков в запросе

Comment: Ну и собственно по ошибке в success если выполучаете html то в success должно быть нечто `function(html) {let count = $(html).find('a[data-id='+id+'] span').text(); // и установка счётчика в нужный элемент}`

Comment: А сейчас визуально вы просто обращаетесь к необъявленному элементу `element`

Comment: При том дважды, вначале вы  в нём получаете спан, потом в этот же спан тот же самый текст записываете

Comment: element - прошу прощения код я скопировал отсюда https://vk-book.ru/ajax-lajkidizlajki-dlya-zapisej/ , там element является аргументов функции

Comment: "Прошу прощения" но если вы копируете код копируйте его до конца или разбирайте до конца

Comment: А почему количество лайков должно увеличиваться по кнопке? А пока не нажмешь на кнопку,  должно отображаться число лайков актуальное на момент перехода на страницу? Как-то неюзабильно.

Comment: так оно и отображается. Значение из таблицы БД берется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = this;
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function () {
    var c = parseInt($(a).find('span').text()) || 0;
    $(a).find('span').text(c + 1);
  },
```

Comment: спасибо, действительно работает

Answer (score -1):

Ну хорошо, как теперь полученное значение записать в span? я что-то делаю не так

```
<p class="like-counter">
    <a data-id="<?=$id;?>" class="counter pull-right">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> <span><?=$comment['vote'];?></span>
    </a>
</p>

$('.like-counter').on('click', '.counter', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var id = $(this).data('id');
$.ajax({
    url: location.href,
    data: {id: id},
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (html) {
        var count = $(html).find('a[data-id=' + id + '] span').text();
        // $('.counter span').html(count++);
        console.log(count);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Error, try again.');
    }
});
});
```